# Can't get the correct execution time value for transaction controller with prev.getTime() in JSR sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

fellow QAs!
Background - apache jmeter 4.0 is used in combination with ChromeWebDriver for loadtesting a jsf web application. In jmeter numerous JSR223\Groovy samplers are used to control locally started chromedriver by executing org.openqa.selenium methods. My current task is to implement pacing. I took this tutorial - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter as a basis, and it looks to work ok at first, but there's one problem, kind of a strange one, that I can't defeat. When I put several jsr223 samplers under a transaction controller, and place another JSR right after it, with this code:

```
//Sets the pacing length based on the last requests response time. 4500 is the time in ms
Long pacing = 4500 - prev.getTime();

//If the response time is less than 4500 ms, set the delay value to myDelay
if ( pacing > 0 ) 
{ 
    //iPacing is equal to the int value of pacing if pacing is not equal to null, otherwise iPacing is null
    Integer iPacing = pacing != null ? pacing.intValue() : null; 
    log.info(String.valueOf(iPacing));
    vars.put("myDelay", String.valueOf(iPacing)); 
    return iPacing; 
}
//The response time is greater than or equal to 4500 ms, set myDelay to 0
else 
{ 
    vars.put("myDelay", "0");
    return 0; 
}
```

the prev.getTime() method returns execution time only for the last sampler under a transaction controller, not the total time! I tried setting and unsetting "Generate parent sample" checkbox - result is still the same.
Here is how the scenario looks:
[image] 
Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) is a different beast, you can fetch total transaction controller execution time as [`prev.getParent().getTime()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getParent--)

Just in case if you need individual Transaction Controller's children you can go for [`prev.getParent().getSubResults()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSubResults--) function:

```
prev.getParent().getSubResults().each {result ->
    log.info('Sampler: ' + result.getSampleLabel() + ' Elapsed time: ' + result.getTime() )
}
```